# Using a subscription inside a snapshotChanges() to retrieve values with Firestore

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore, angular2-observables

I'm not an expert to build an app, but I need to find a document of a collection by an id of another document in another collection.
I need to populate an object (Tenant) that has another object (RealEstate) inside of it.

So the fist thing that I'm doing is using **snapshotChanges** and **map** to get the Contract. 
This contract has an ID as property, and with this ID I want to make a new consult to the database to retrieve the RealEstate refering to that id and with this, populate the data of the Contract.RealEstate...

Please see the code above:

```
  public contracts: Observable<Contract[]>;
  // I tried to use this property but it does not work... 
  public currentRealEstate: RealEstate = null;
  ... 

  this.contracts = this.afDb.collection<Contract>(
  'Contract',
  ref => ref.where('ownerId', '==', this.fb.user.uid).where("active", "==", true)
  ).snapshotChanges().pipe(
   map(actions => actions.map(a => {
    const data = a.payload.doc.data() as Contract;
    const id = a.payload.doc.id;
    data.id = id;

    // This is where I'm doing wrong... 
    this.afDb.doc<RealEstate>('RealEstate/' + data.realEstateId).valueChanges().
      subscribe((data) => {

        // attr the RealEstate data to the property... 
        this.currentRealEstate = data;  

        console.log(this.currentRealEstate); // return is ok on the log...
      });

    // attr the property to the Contract.realEstate...   
    data.realEstate = this.currentRealEstate; 

    return { id, ...data };
  }))
```

What do I need to do to?
Thanks and I'm sorry if I said something wrong.